# While Loop CSV File Login - Loops 3 times, unsure why

Tags: python, csv, while-loop, python-3.3

```
import csv

def login():
    global student
    student = []
    file = open("student.csv","r")       
    data = csv.reader(file)    

    UsernameVerified = False
    PasswordVerified = False

    while UsernameVerified == False:
        username = input("Username: ")
        for row in data:
            user = []
            student.append(row)
            print(UsernameVerified)

            for multi in row[5:6]:
                if username in multi:
                    print("found")
                    UsernameVerified = True
                    print(UsernameVerified)
```

This is the current code I am using. However when I run this code and put in the correct user name, it finds the user 3 times which it shouldn't be doing.

Also when I put in the wrong user then the right user, it cannot find the user at all.

I am doing this for a school project and have had 2 teachers look into this, so far no progress was made.

[Output when I input the correct User first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0YxY.png)

[Output when I input the wrong User first, then the Correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raMc9.png)

New code 
——————

import csv

def login():
    global student
    student = []

```
UsernameVerified = False
PasswordVerified = False

while UsernameVerified == False:
        file = open("student.csv","r")
        data = csv.reader(file)
        username = input("Username: ")
        for row in data:
            user = []
            student.append(row)
            print(UsernameVerified)

            for user in row[5:6]:
                if username in user:
                    print("found")
                    UsernameVerified = True
                    print(UsernameVerified)

while PasswordVerified == False:
        file = open("student.csv","r")
        data = csv.reader(file)
        password = input("Password: ")
        for row in data:
            user = []
            student.append(row)
            print(PasswordVerified)

            for pass1 in row[4:5]:
                if password in pass1:
                    print("found")
                    PasswordVerified = True
                    print(PasswordVerified)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to give an example of `student.csv`

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: it returns 3 times because the while loop only stops and the end of for loop. if you want a quick fix use "break" inside for loop when you log in the user

For the second question that happens because "data" variable is pointed to the end of file. Basically you open the file, read it until the end when you enter the wrong user, and it stays there. try opening the file only after the "input" using a "with" statement

Comment: I tried to use break but it unfortunately didn’t work. I have fixed the problem with the data (I still have to try the method you have provided). The method I have used is not very efficient but it works.

Comment: can you post changes? notice you'd have to break from both for loops

Comment: This is the code I’m using now, it’s not efficient but it works.